# Will PDFToImage Extract embedded images also - pdfbox?

Tags: pdfbox

Would `PDFToImage` command do the image extraction also ?

I want to convert the `PDF` files To `Image` `(PDFBOX)`

I am using `PDFToImage` command for pdf to image file conversion,but i'm missing All Embedded images in PDF when I ran `PDFToImage`.

Or Do I need to Run Extract Images separately to extract images from PDFFiles?

Is there any other way to Achieve this ???

thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 3):

`PDFToImage` is converting PDF pages into images and output one image per page.
You are looking for `ExtractImages` which extracts all embedded images of a PDF document.

More information about `ExtractImages` can be found there:

http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/ExtractImages.html

To answer your question more specifically, these two programs do different things. You can recode a single one that gathers the two functionalities, or run them separately.

Comment: PDFToImage is misleading because it actually just extracts out text into the new image. It's not actually turning the whole PDF to an Image...